# gdb shows strange symbol-less thread causes SIGSEGV - What is it?

Tags: php, linux, gdb, pthreads

I have problems with php-cgi in that it segfaults every so often.  The parent php-cgi spawns 210 others and it's one of these children that fails.

I have built a debug copy of it (-g -O0) and loaded debug symbols for glibc etc.  When I look at the core dump I get this:

```
delivery101:/cored# gdb /usr/bin/php-cgi 28133_1446799964.core 
GNU gdb (GDB) CentOS (7.0.1-45.el5.centos)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".

Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php-cgi...done.
Attaching to program: /usr/bin/php-cgi, process 28133
ptrace: No such process.
[New Thread 28195]
[New Thread 28133]
Reading symbols from /lib64/libcrypt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so.debug...done
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/librt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/librt-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libm-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libdl-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libnsl.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libnsl-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib64/libcom_err.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libcom_err.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libssl.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libssl.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libcrypto.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libcrypto.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libc-2.5.so.debug...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libresolv.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libresolv-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libresolv.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libpthread-2.5.so.debug...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/ld-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libselinux.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libselinux.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libsepol.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libsepol.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so.debug...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libnss_files.so.2

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff6956d000
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/php-cgi'.
    Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002af461e02678 in ?? ()
```

So I look at what threads are there:

```
(gdb) info threads
  2 Thread 0x2af45de68af0 (LWP 28133)  0x000000315da48370 in krb5int_kt_finalize () from /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3
* 1 Thread 0x2af487823940 (LWP 28195)  0x00002af461e02678 in ?? ()
```

As I understand it the * next to thread 1 indicates that this was the thread that caused the segfault.  So I had a closer look at that:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00002af461e02678 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000018733e78 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00002af4878230c0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00002af487823100 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00002af461dfed8d in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

I don't know where the thread came from (or how to find out) and I can't see what use the backtrace could be; Is the lack of symbols just that I haven't loaded symbols for everything or could it be that it is indicative of the problem itself (buffer overrun?)

My question is:  How can I find out where this thread came from and what it is?

If you need any more details, just let me know.

Comment: This is a stab in the dark ... It's possible that the core is generated after Zend unloaded modules, try regenerating the core by executing with ```ZEND_DONT_UNLOAD_MODULES=1``` in ENV

Comment: What you really need is to catch a process in the act of crashing, by executing the parent with gdb and using ```set follow-fork-mode child```, you may still need to prohibit zend unloading modules as above.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out where this thread came from and what it is?

There are several likely possibilities for the useless stack trace you got:

1. You are analyzing the core produced by optimized php-cgi, but giving GDB the debug version of php-cgi. That simply doesn't work: you need to analyze the core using the binary that produced that core.
2. You may be analyzing the core dump on a machine (e.g. development) which is different from the one (e.g. production) where the core was produced. It's possible to do this, but you must be careful to make GDB use the *exact* versions of shared libraries that were used at the time of the core dump.
3. It's possible that while installing debug symbols for glibc, etc. you've also updated some libraries, leading to mismatch between what was used at time of core dump, and what is used at time of analysis.
4. It's possible that php-cgi uses some kind of `JIT` compilation, and the crash is happening in `JIT`ted code.
5. It's possible that the program simply jumped to random address that doesn't correspond to any function at all.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: 1. The debug version is compiled with -O0, so no optimisation.
2. The build and run are on the same machine.
3. Whenever I change the build I gather new core dumps.
4. I hadn't thought of that.  Any idea of how to investigate?
5. Yes, it's possible, but I need to know why.